# Does react parent component wait for the children to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that has 800 children (a list).

I want to scroll the list to a pre-defined position X.

I have something like this in the Parent:

`useEffect(() => /* scroll the list */, [])`

Does the parent component's `useEffect` hook get called only after all children have been rendered or not?

I'm having a bug when I'm trying to scroll toward the end of the list. It feels like the end of the list doesn't exist yet when `useEffect` is called.

Comment: Is a list of 800 a good UX in the first place? I'd consider pagination and selecting the appropriate page.

Comment: @isherwood I guess I just want to know better how React works :) Let's assume it's an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
const C1: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
console.log(1);

React.use Effect(() => {
console.log(2)});

return <>{children}</>
}

const C2: React.FC = () => {
console.log(3);

React.use Effect(() => {
console.log(4)});

return <div>YOWZA</div>
}

const App = () => <C1><C2/></C1>
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Order of console.log are 1,3,4,2.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time! Can you do the same with 800xC2 and removed useEffect from C2? Then it would be what I'm working with. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you are not using virtualization, then the order will be as follows:
Parent Body, Child 1 Body, Child 2 Body, ... , Last Child Body, Parent useEffect.
IMPORTANT: The order will be as follows if you've rendered the entire list.